# AWS SES: Receiving a email replay with an attachment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am working on a project where I am sending an email using SES and expecting a response from the user. The response will have a csv file attached to it.
I see that I can read the attached file in the response but do I have to save it in S3 to be able to read it? Is it possible for me to read the file in memory using a lambda function?
My goal is to avoid using S3 b.c it is a overkill for my use case, I do not need the save the conetent for the attachmnet. All I want to do is get the data from the attachment.

In short: Can I parse(read) the content of a attachment in a email response without saving the file 1st?

Thanks for your help!

I am just doing research right now and trying to find example of someone that has already done this.